# Google Apps script state token is invalid or has expired

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, token, laravel-passport

Connecting to non-Google Service from a Gmail add-on using [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services). In the resource server part use Laravel Passport (here's an [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTFPMAX_88s) of using Laravel Passport).Getting state token is invalid or has expired error when click Authorize after filling login and password.

Here's my code:

```
function accessProtectedResource(url, method_opt, headers_opt) {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  var maybeAuthorized = service.hasAccess();
  if (maybeAuthorized) {
    // A token is present, but it may be expired or invalid. Make a
    // request and check the response code to be sure.

    // Make the UrlFetch request and return the result.
    var accessToken = service.getAccessToken();
    var method = method_opt || 'get';
    var headers = headers_opt || {};
    headers['Authorization'] =
        Utilities.formatString('Bearer %s', accessToken);
    var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
      'headers': headers,
      'method' : method,
      'muteHttpExceptions': true, // Prevents thrown HTTP exceptions.
    });

    var code = resp.getResponseCode();
    if (code >= 200 && code < 300) {
      return resp.getContentText("utf-8"); // Success
    } else if (code == 401 || code == 403) {
       // Not fully authorized for this action.
       maybeAuthorized = false;
    } else {
       // Handle other response codes by logging them and throwing an
       // exception.
       console.error("Backend server error (%s): %s", code.toString(),
                     resp.getContentText("utf-8"));
       throw ("Backend server error: " + code);
    }
  }

  if (!maybeAuthorized) {
    // Invoke the authorization flow using the default authorization
    // prompt card.
    CardService.newAuthorizationException()
        .setAuthorizationUrl(service.getAuthorizationUrl())
        .setResourceDisplayName("Display name to show to the user 321")
        .throwException();
  }
}

function getOAuthService() {
  return OAuth2.createService('Test Gmail add-on2')
      .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://example.com/oauth/authorize')
      .setTokenUrl('https://example.com/oauth/token')
      .setClientId(4)
      .setClientSecret('qwerty_client_secret')
      .setScope('')
      .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
      .setParam('response_type', 'code')
      .setParam('state', getCallbackURL('authCallback'))
      .setCache(CacheService.getUserCache())
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties());
}

function getCallbackURL(callbackFunction) {
  // IMPORTANT: Replace string below with the URL from your script, minus the /edit at the end.
  var scriptUrl = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/qwertyuyuioplkjjhggsdfgfgs';
  var urlSuffix = '/usercallback?state=';
  var stateToken = ScriptApp.newStateToken()
      .withMethod(callbackFunction)
      .withTimeout(120)
      .createToken();
  return scriptUrl + urlSuffix + stateToken;
}

function authCallback(callbackRequest) {
  var authorized = getOAuthService().handleCallback(callbackRequest);
  if (authorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(
      'Success! <script>setTimeout(function() { top.window.close() }, 1);</script>');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied');
  }
}

function resetOAuth() {
  getOAuthService().reset();
}
```

UPDATED:

Attached screen of error dialog.

[image: screen of error]

This is error link with two `state` query parameter - https://script.google.com/a/macros/domain.com/d/SCRIPT_ID/usercallback?code=SOME_CODE&state=https%3A%2F%2Fscript.google.com%2Fmacros%2Fd%2F1Y4O73MuraCLhHstyykqNcA5SYtyiwQvYeFaJWdPJOtxWY57cj0WLDKEh%2Fusercallback%3Fstate%3SOME_LONG_HASH

Comment: From what I understand your Oauth Laravel Passport is working out of the box, right? Can you share in which part of your code the error is thrown? Is it in this part `throw ("Backend server error: " + code);`?

Comment: @Emel, it doesn't go the ``throw``. Because of maybeAuthorized is false.

Comment: Updated the question. Added screen and url of that screen page.

Comment: From what I see in the [WebApp Example](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples/WebApp) the URL structure seems to be different, right? And also, you refer that you want an approximation of [Add-on](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/Add-on/Code.gs)? Have you checked the samples folder? Maybe there is one that can help you to set up your environment correctly.

Comment: It seems laravel is not sending the ``state``  correctly.

Comment: There's no ``state`` param in the WebApp and Add-on examples. Laravel Passport is requires state params.

Comment: From what I see in the [laravel passport documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#requesting-tokens) `state` is just a random string of 40 characters: `$state = Str::random(40)`, so as long as this `getCallbackURL('authCallback')`  returns a matching string, it should not interfere with the authentication process. `The consumer should verify the "state" parameter against the value that was stored prior to the redirect`

Comment: I've tried with random string (40 length) and there are still invalid token. Tried without passing state param and getting error ``The request is missing a required parameter.... at Service_.getTokenFromResponse_(Service:553:11)``

Comment: The redirect from laravel isn't passing the state correctly. Contact laravel support